# Nginx config file isn't locating my Codeigniter/PHP app

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, app-config, server-configuration

I can't figure out how to make the Nginx config file locate my Codeigniter app. Serving PHP on this server is not the problem b/c if I put a php file in my root directory, I can `echo "hello world";`.

Here's my Nginx config file which is nearly verbatim from [this tutorial](http://johanndutoit.blogspot.com/2012/04/setup-nginx-for-codeigniter-on-ubuntu.html).  Note that I've manipulated many of these parameters and none had an effext so I'm wondering whether I need to look beyond this file to get it to work?:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    root   /var/www;
    index index.html index.php index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log; 
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;  

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I've been thinking all along this is a simple path issue b/c Codeigniter has a somewhat confusing routing structure but just can't see the problem with my config. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you modify your Codeigniter's configurations to work with Nginx? Your Nginx's configurations looks fine.

Comment: @AzizAG My Codeigniter 2.1.2 configuration seems standard. I have a default controller named "main", got rid of "index.php" in the URL via the config/config.php. My system, application folders and the CI index.php file are in root directory. I have an Apache server with a generic .htaccess file and that serves up my CI app fine so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I would give it a shot without the index.php removal in place and see if you can get it to work. That'll at least narrow down the problem.

Comment: @jpea, you mean by restoring in the config/config.php file this?: `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` I just tried this and then went to mysite.com/index.php/main but still no luck.

Comment: yep, that's what I was suggesting. I posted my config below as an answer. It might work?

Comment: also, this is my whole config file for the CI/Nginx project - http://pastebin.com/0eREMSMz

Answer (score 1):

Everything up top matches what I have for a CI project, then this is my location config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_index  index.php;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Not sure if by removing the wildcard * would help, or getting rid of the split_info param...

Comment: -@jpea, thanks, hmm, I just copied your pastebin code nearly exactly (my root is /var/www). Now I'm getting a 403 Nginx forbidden error. Out of desperation I then did `root@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx:~# sudo chmod 777 /var/www` but that didn't correct the 403. Can't tell this is better or worse, thoughts?

Comment: -@jpea, the 403 is specific to the CI directories/files as serving up a php file from the /var/www root still works just fine. Ugh, really wish I knew permissions better...